# Need a list of third party video services that i can offload the conversion and serving up of my private videos?

Tags: 6, files

Can anyone help me to narrow down a list of third party video services that i can offload the conversion and serving up of my private videos?

Requirements are:

1. Already have a Drupal 6 module that integrates the api (Also has a D7 future)
2. Must allow the video to only be viewed on my Drupal site. Not on their site (e.g. not viewable on YouTube)
3. HTML 5/Flash fall back (would be nice, but not necessary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

- [ZenCoder](http://zencoder.com/)
- [Bits on the Run](http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run)
- [Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/)

with [Video module](http://drupal.org/project/video)

Answer (score 0):

youtube has an option for "private videos", they won't show up on the youtube site but you can still embed them in your site. Not a slick solution but it's free ;-)